# using celery events for transferring python log records

Tags: python, logging, celery

We use celery as a sort of home made map-reduce tool, where we run jobs parallel on multiple workers and wait for the results. We are using celery events to transport python logging messages on the worker back to the client. I know we can use a log aggregation tool like sentry, but it is important for us that these log messages are returned to the client. Question is, how do I register a celery event listener on the client, without a thread? Also, is this what we are doing completely wrong or not? It works for us, but maybe there is a better way.

I've created a working example in github:

https://github.com/gijzelaerr/celerylog

Below a small explanation what we are doing.

On the worker we run this:

```
class TaskLogEmitter(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, celery_app, level=logging.NOTSET):
        self.celery_app = celery_app
        super(TaskLogEmitter, self).__init__(level=level)

    def emit(self, record):
        with self.celery_app.events.default_dispatcher() as d:
            d.send('task-log', msg=record.getMessage(), levelno=record.levelno,
                   pathname=record.pathname, lineno=record.lineno,
                   name=record.name,  exc_info=record.exc_info)

@after_setup_logger.connect
@after_setup_task_logger.connect
def setup_task_log_emitter(logger=None, **kwargs):
    """
    setup log handler
    """
    handler = TaskLogEmitter(celery_app)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

This will register a python log handler and emit a celery event for every log record. On the client we have a even monitor function:

```
def monitor_events(celery_app):
    def on_event(event):
        logger = logging.getLogger(event['name'])
        logger.log(event['levelno'],event.msg)

    with celery_app.connection() as conn:
        recv = celery_app.events.Receiver(conn, handlers={'task-log':
on_event})
        recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)
```

which we start in a thread otherwise it blocks:

```
def setup_event_listening(celery_app):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_events, args=[celery_app])
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
```

Comment: This question has provided me with an idea on how to create custom events. Celery emits only standard tasks are {'sent','started','succeeded',...}. Thanks for this.